# Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.primefaces.model.TreeNode on deployment on websphere

Tags: java, maven, jsf, primefaces, websphere

Recently i had integrated my web application project with maven which was earlier working fine. On integration, i am finding this error for which i have no clue. I checked if any of my dependancies were missing in my pom.xml but what all were required were already present. I seriously have no idea of how to proceed or how to debug my issue. I am able fire all my commands using maven and getting build success too. This is my initial phase with maven and would request the expertise here to guide me to proper directions. Below is my source code for POM.

Below is my error log:

```
Faces Servlet: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.primefaces.model.TreeNode
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:221)
```

class for my web path entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**/*.java" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/asm/asm-commons/3.3/asm-commons-3.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/asm/asm-tree/3.3/asm-tree-3.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/asm/asm/3.3/asm-3.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_34/lib/tools.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/antlr/antlr/2.7.2/antlr-2.7.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/primefaces/primefaces/5.0/primefaces-5.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/easymock/easymock/2.4/easymock-2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/testng/testng/6.8.8/testng-6.8.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/beust/jcommander/1.27/jcommander-1.27.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/mockito/mockito-all/1.9.5/mockito-all-1.9.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.3.16.3/struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/struts/xwork/xwork-core/2.3.16.3/xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/ognl/ognl/3.0.6/ognl-3.0.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javassist/javassist/3.11.0.GA/javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.19/freemarker-2.3.19.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3.1/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/tiles/tiles-core/2.0.6/tiles-core-2.0.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/tiles/tiles-api/2.0.6/tiles-api-2.0.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/opensymphony/xwork/2.0.3/xwork-2.0.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/opensymphony/ognl/2.6.11/ognl-2.6.11.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/struts/struts2-convention-plugin/2.3.16.3/struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/struts/struts-taglib/1.3.10/struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/struts/struts-core/1.3.10/struts-core-1.3.10.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-chain/commons-chain/1.2/commons-chain-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.3.1/commons-validator-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/json/json/20140107/json-20140107.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/protocol/arquillian-protocol-servlet/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-protocol-servlet-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/container/arquillian-container-spi/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-container-spi-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/core/arquillian-core-spi/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-core-spi-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/core/arquillian-core-api/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-core-api-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/config/arquillian-config-api/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-config-api-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base/2.0.0-alpha-5/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base-2.0.0-alpha-5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/config/arquillian-config-impl-base/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-config-impl-base-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi/2.0.0-alpha-5/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi-2.0.0-alpha-5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/easytesting/fest-assert/1.4/fest-assert-1.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/easytesting/fest-util/1.1.6/fest-util-1.1.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-api/1.2.2/shrinkwrap-api-1.2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/container/arquillian-container-test-api/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-container-test-api-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/container/arquillian-container-test-spi/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-container-test-spi-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/test/arquillian-test-spi/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-test-spi-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/test/arquillian-test-api/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-test-api-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/junit/arquillian-junit-container/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-junit-container-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/junit/arquillian-junit-core/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-junit-core-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/core/arquillian-core-impl-base/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/test/arquillian-test-impl-base/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-test-impl-base-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/container/arquillian-container-impl-base/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-container-impl-base-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/container/arquillian-container-test-impl-base/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-container-test-impl-base-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-impl-base/1.2.2/shrinkwrap-impl-base-1.2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-spi/1.2.2/shrinkwrap-spi-1.2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/container/arquillian-wlp-managed-8.5/1.0.0.Beta1/arquillian-wlp-managed-8.5-1.0.0.Beta1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/testenricher/arquillian-testenricher-cdi/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-testenricher-cdi-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/testenricher/arquillian-testenricher-ejb/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-testenricher-ejb-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/testenricher/arquillian-testenricher-resource/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-testenricher-resource-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/arquillian/testenricher/arquillian-testenricher-initialcontext/1.1.4.Final/arquillian-testenricher-initialcontext-1.1.4.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/spec/javax/servlet/jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec/1.0.2.Final/jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/2.9/maven-eclipse-plugin-2.9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.8/maven-project-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.0.8/maven-settings-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.0.8/maven-model-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.6/plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-9-stable-1/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/classworlds/classworlds/1.1/classworlds-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.0.8/maven-profile-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.8/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0.8/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.8/maven-artifact-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/2.1/wagon-provider-api-2.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-registry/2.0.8/maven-plugin-registry-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.8/maven-plugin-api-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-core/2.0.8/maven-core-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-file/1.0-beta-2/wagon-file-1.0-beta-2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter/2.0.8/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-lightweight/1.0-beta-2/wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-shared/1.0-beta-2/wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/jtidy/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev/jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.8/maven-reporting-api-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-9/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-error-diagnostics/2.0.8/maven-error-diagnostics-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ssh-external/1.0-beta-2/wagon-ssh-external-1.0-beta-2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ssh-common/1.0-beta-2/wagon-ssh-common-1.0-beta-2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-descriptor/2.0.8/maven-plugin-descriptor-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-monitor/2.0.8/maven-monitor-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ssh/1.0-beta-2/wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.27/jsch-0.1.27.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-jline/1.0-alpha-5/plexus-interactivity-jline-1.0-alpha-5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/jline/jline/0.9.1/jline-0.9.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.2/maven-archiver-2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-resources/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-resources-1.0-alpha-7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/biz/aQute/bndlib/0.0.145/bndlib-0.0.145.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-osgi/0.2.0/maven-osgi-0.2.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/eclipse/core/resources/3.3.0-v20070604/resources-3.3.0-v20070604.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/javaee-api/6.0/javaee-api-6.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/myprojectCommon"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/myprojectEJB"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/myprojectJPA"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Looks like you have another version, probably 3.2, of primefaces in websphere's lib\ext folder.

Comment: @Mubin : Are you talking about webshpere lib folder or in my maven repository??.

Comment: in Websphere's lib folder.

Comment: I dont have a primefaces jar inside my websphere folder...Can this be an issue???

Comment: As I understand you are using scope compile because all libs are in ear. I suppose that ear contains primefaces. In this case the problem can be related with jsf-api libraries versions.

Comment: Do you have jsf-api / jsf-impl jar in your websphere?

Comment: For runtime primefaces 5 uses 'com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:2.+'

Comment: @Multisync : I have neither of the jars in my websphere.how do i proceed. :(

Comment: Strange... How it worked before upgrade... You need to download these jars and create shared library in sphere for your app server. It's quite simple

Comment: Sorry, I think it's not your case because error says that primefaces class is not found. Check your classpath first - is the primefaces there?

Comment: @Multisync : i have added my classpath entries. If you can please have a look and guide me through.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63486/discussion-between-multisync-and-shirish).

Comment: @Multisync : i dont have jsf-api.jar listed in my pom.xml..could this be an issue?

Comment: @Shirish Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121606/after-upgrading-from-primefaces-3-2-to-3-4-1-noclassdeffounderror-org-primefa

Comment: @Multisync : But there is a primefaces.jar listed in my classpath.:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even i had the same issue. Just check your POM.xml if you have incuded the below line while creating your war plugin.

```
<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
```

Comment this line and then try. I guess your issue should be solved.